# SwiperJS: How can I enable both direction vertical and horizontal swipe event

Tags: javascript, direction, swiper.js

I have using SwipperJS form some slider which I need enable the swipe events vertical and horizontal, bot. the option 'direction' only allow `direction: 'vertical'|'horizontal'` only one direction, so how can I enable both direction for swipe events swipe to bottom and top, left and right to change to the next slide or previus slide.

Comment: sorry many typos here.... SwipperJS for* some ..... horizontal, both* the option....

Answer (score 1):

please check nested swiper [here](https://swiperjs.com/demos/#nested_swipers)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-18-nested-swipers?file=index.html

Horizontal slider 2 has 4 vertical sliders nested.

Comment: Hi! thank you, good approach, but I won't create an slider inside the other slide. I need the same slider detect the slide-up, slide-down, slide-left, slide-right events to change the same batch of slides

Comment: there is no way except nested swiper on swiper.js, you can check another library here. https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page2/1